# iOS Background Refresh interval

Tags: ios

There is not much documentation on the iOS 7 Background Refresh interval other than that it depends on how often user opens the app.  I would appreciate any insights into the refresh interval per your testing.

E.x.
If my app is used approximately once a week, how often would my app be able to refresh in the background?

What about user opening app twice a week?

Comment: The algorithm for this is not public as far as I am aware, so you would probably be better off testing it yourself.

Comment: You are right about the algorithm not being public but I am hoping the collective knowledge of this community can shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the background fetch to `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` the iOS will intelligently study the usage pattern of your app and match the fetch frequency accordingly. In other words the iOS will try to predict when the user normally use your app and schedule the fetch to fit it (awesome right!). If you want to hear all about it you should watch session 204 in WWDC2013 (https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/).

Comment: Thanks but I have already read the official docs and watched the wwdc video.  I want to know beyond what apple docs say.